# No such file or directory - H:/ (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails project which I'm trying to bundle on Windows Server 2013.

I have successfully built and tested the app on my local windows 7 machine and have successfully bundled and ran a rails server on another Windows Server 2013 which has been successful.

Now, when bundling to the main server, I'm getting the following:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot>bundle
Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:54
:in `stat': No such file or directory - H:/ (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_
fetcher.rb:54:in `initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/source.rb:253:in `new'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/source.rb:253:in `fetch_all_remote_specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/source.rb:234:in `block in remote_specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/source.rb:231:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/source.rb:231:in `remote_specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/source.rb:165:in `fetch_specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/source.rb:70:in `specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/definition.rb:176:in `block (2 levels) in index'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/definition.rb:175:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/definition.rb:175:in `block in index'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/index.rb:7:in `build'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `index'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/definition.rb:168:in `resolve'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/definition.rb:107:in `specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/definition.rb:102:in `resolve_remotely!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/installer.rb:43:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/cli.rb:219:in `install'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22
/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

I also receive a similar error when trying this:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot>gem install win32-service
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
    No such file or directory - H:/
```

My RubyGems Environment:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.16
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-02-16 patchlevel 125) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I have tried re-installing rails via RailsInstaller and restarted the machine. Command Prompt is also being run as Administrator.

Anyone have any theories?

Comment: did you install this stuff from a shared directory?

Comment: hello, everything is on the local disk (C:) which is not shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue - the server did not have a default gateway so was not reaching our TMG server.